# MySQL: User Defined Function Used in WHERE x IN (...) Not working

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, where-in

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that takes a single parameter that can consist of 1 or more values.  I want to be able to filter by these values, so I created a function that can take a string and a delimiter parameter

```
my_func('val1,val2,val3',',')
```

and it returns a string

```
'val1','val2','val3'
```

.  I am then calling this function in the where clause such as

```
WHERE x IN (my_func('val1,val2,val3',','))
```

But this is not working.  It does not give any error, but it keeps running without ever returning anything.  I have tested the function individually and it works fine and returns in less than a second.  The query I am trying to run it in is a test query that is very basic.  Replacing the function with a regular string such as

```
WHERE x IN ('val1','val2','val3')
```

works perfectly fine and returns in just a couple seconds.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?  Thanks!

Comment: I am confused to what your stored proc is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @FutbolFan It takes a comma-delimited list and returns a comma-delimited list with quotes around each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IN` requires the argument to be a literal list, it doesn't re-parse the string. Use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(x, 'val1,val2,val3'))
```

Comment: Wow this answer is so underrated.